# Deliberate timing delay in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Dear Netlogo community,

I want to put some timer constraint in my simulation for agents to make decision. I know we can implement by using ticks but in my simulation all agents should make decision with in a tick and to avoid any deadlock I want to introduce some time constraint for agent to make decision. If agent does not make the decision with in specified time the control of resource should go to other agent. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that there's a more fundamental issue here. Putting in a delay will slow down the simulation, but won't actually change the order that NetLogo processes commands. The agents (turtles) are not actually doing their decisions concurrently. When you do `ask turtles [...]`, one turtle does everything in [], then the next etc until all turtles have done it before moving on to the next set of commands. So you probably want something more like `ask turtles with [some sort of filter about resource availability][commands]` then `ask turtles with [different filter][different commands]`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any constraint related to any tick limit you could make a procedure that counts a number of ticks since the main turtle procedure started, something like...

**EDITED** Code:

```
procedure turtle-decision-making
set time_passed 0
while time_passed < time_limit
  decision-taking-part << 
     if decision taken
      break while loop
     else
     set time_passed (ticks_passed + 1)
  ;; tick Might be that this procedure is the outermost loop, might be that is not.
end while
end turtle-decision-making
```

Comment: I like this suggestion, except that I wouldn't call the time units of the agent's deliberation "ticks", since that's NetLogo's terminology for time progressing in the simulation as a whole. All of your code is running inside a single tick.

Comment: @SethTisue Updated the code so that it ticks inside the loop. What do you think?

Comment: My suggestion to avoid using the tick counter for this at all. In a NetLogo context, it basically never makes sense to modify the tick counter in an inner loop, only in the simulation's outermost loop. So I'm suggesting keeping `ticks_passed`, but giving it a different name, one that doesn't have `tick` in it, which is misleading in a specifically NetLogo context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to halt the turtle based on how much CPU or "wall clock" time has passed, that it simply isn't possible in NetLogo. There's no way to stop an arbitrary piece of NetLogo code in its tracks from the outside without halting the entire model. Besides, NetLogo is single threaded, so there's only ever one piece of NetLogo code running at any given time, so there's no way to have other NetLogo code interrupt or intervene.

You'll have to do something more like what JenB suggests, or like what David suggests -- both seem like potentially valid approaches, depending on your goals.